# Is the Bias Vector a Column or Row Vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading through a book on neural networks and was wondering whether in the equation the bias vector is a row or column vector. I would assume it is a row vector because we have designated the columns to represent the outputs of each artificial neuron, therefore it would follow that the vector should be a row vector. Please let me know if I am wrong about something.

[Neural Network Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yWIG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here, $X$ is an $N \times M$ matrix and $W$ must be an $M \times K$ matrix, so $XW$ is $N \times K$. That means $b$ must be $N \times K$, unless the machine learning people are forging ahead in their campaign to develop a parallel and unreadable dialect of statistics.

Comment: Yeah, the book is not exactly the most eloquent. I think that b is a 1 by K (one column for every artificial neuron) vector added to each row. At least the only thing that makes sense to me.

Comment: If $b$ is $1\times K$ then the equation in the book is an abuse of mathematical notation so egregious as to make notation almost worthless.

Comment: @DavidK I asked around and it is notation. I agree, it is extremely misleading. I think they use it because in Python you are allowed to add a vector and a matrix column or row wise. As a math student, it makes 0 sense to me and I am glad to see others agree.

Comment: R says: > matrix(1,2,2)+matrix(1,2,1)
Error in matrix(1, 2, 2) + matrix(1, 2, 1) : non-conformable arrays .  R can be a pain about many things, but if you use = as assignment instead of '<-' to ensure variables are local and not global, I like it over the alternatives for data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Is "b" the bias vector?  I am wondering about the product XW.  In order for that to make sense the number of columns of X must equal the number of rows of W.  We are told that X "has one column per feature" and W "has one row per input neuron".  Are the "number of features" equal to the number of "input neurons"?  If so then the multiplication can be done and the result is a matrix with number of columns equal to the number of columns of W and number of rows equal to the number of rows of X.  The number of columns of W is the number of "artificial neurons in the layer" and the number of rows in X is the number of "instances".  In order that XW be a vector, so we can add b, one or those must be 1.  b is a row vector if the number or "instances" is 1 and a column vector if the number or "artificial neurons in the layer" is 1.

Comment: Yes the multiplication can be done. The input neurons are equal to the features, so we have an N by M matrix (instance matrix) and M by K matrix (output for each instance). So I think that when they say add b (the bias vector) they mean add it to every row, so that is why I assume it is a row vector.